# Finding the inverse function of $f(x) = -(9x^2 + 6x + 2)e^{-3x}$ using the generalised Lambert function.

Tags: exponential-function, quadratics, inverse-function, lambert-w

I just learned about the generalized lambert function and I was trying to use it to find the inverse of a function. I have solved the equation below, so can someone check if it is correct? 
Thanks in advance.
$$f(x) = -(9x^2 + 6x + 2)e^{-3x}$$
$$-9f(x)= (-3x-1-i)(-3x-1+i)e^{-3x}$$
by using the generalised lambert function we get,
$$-3x = W\left(-1-i, -1+i; -9f \right)$$
Therefore,
$$x = {-1 \over 3}W\left(-1-i, -1+i; -9f \right)$$

Comment: There was an error in the first version. I have made the change. Sorry for that